# Automatic Updates setting via WMI

Tags: c#, registry, wmi

Attempting to pull the automatic update settings from the registry of a remote server. For some reason, it's returning a 0 even though a manual check of the key is 1-4. What am I overlooking? Snippet below:

```
ManagementScope msAutoUpdateReg = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + remoteServer + @"\root\DEFAULT:StdRegProv", connection);
msAutoUpdateReg.Connect();

ManagementClass ci = new ManagementClass(msAutoUpdateReg, new ManagementPath(@"DEFAULT:StdRegProv"), new ObjectGetOptions());
ManagementBaseObject inParams = ci.GetMethodParameters("GetDWORDValue");
inParams["hDefKey"] = 0x80000002; //HKLM
inParams["sSubKeyName"] = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update";
inParams["sValueName"] = "AUOptions";
ManagementBaseObject outParams = ci.InvokeMethod("GetDWORDValue", inParams, null);
UInt32 auValue = (UInt32)outParams["uValue"];

if (auValue.ToString() != "0")
{
    if (auValue == 1)
    {
        string currentSetting = "Keep my computer up to date has been disabled in Automatic Updates.";
    }

    if (auValue == 2)
    {
        string currentSetting = "Notify of download and installation.";
    }

    if (auValue == 3)
    {
        string currentSetting = "Automatically download and notify of installation.";
    }

    if (auValue == 4)
    {
        string currentSetting = "Automatically download and scheduled installation.";
    }
}
else
{
    string currentSetting = "Unknown";
}
```

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts about this? I've now tried multiple things now with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a process of elimination might help here...

1) Is this happening on just one server or are you getting this on all servers? How about on your own local machine? Is it a Windows version thing? For example it seems my Windows 10 box doesn't show the SubKey name you are looking for.

2) Do you also get zero if you change the sValueName to "foo"? Is a value of 0 representing an error?

3) Can you put a watch on outParams and check to see what values have been returned?

4) Are you being blocked by UAC, firewall or other permission issues? Can you execute other WMI commands against this server without any problems? Do you need to Run As Administrator to get this to work?

5) Are you getting an other exceptions or return values? I'm guessing you've posted just a portion of the code here so is this code inside a try/catch block?

Sorry if this sounds either vague or simplistic but I think you may need to look at what does work and what doesn't to see if you can identify a pattern.

Comment: It's good practice to check the return code of the Get operation and to look at the error reference for the API...

Comment: 1. Happens on all servers even when the key exists.
2. Not sure how to change the value to foo.
3. Value returned is 0
4. UAC turned down and firewall disabled. Yes, all other WMI queries return with no issues. Have tried running as Admin plus Administrators of the servers.
5. Correct, just posted the snippet.

Comment: The return value is coming back with 2. I was able to reproduce this by calling the regkey via the command prompt. Standard prompt returns access denied. Elevated to administrator returns the key properly. What would be the easiest way to elevate WMI to administrator for remote servers?